# Tough NL Diff Eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to explore

$$ \left( y'' + (1/x) \, y' \right)(1-y) \,  –  \, (1/x)\left(y'\right)^4 = 0 $$

with the initial conditions $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 1$.

By substitution I can show that an asymptotic solution exists of the form $y = x - (1/4)x^2 - (1/12)x^3$ and it seems to have a decent radius of convergence,

but when I try to run the Taylor expansion further I run into problems in which the coefficients become overconstrained causing attempts to reach higher order in the series to fail.

Any ideas how to approach learning what the solution function looks like at other places along $x$?

WGH

Comment: [y'' + (1/x)y'](1-y) – (1/x)y'^4 = 0

Comment: leading comma should be [

Comment: I have tried to make your question more readable. Please check for any mistake or typo. On the other hand, I would go for using a numerical solver to get a (numerical) solution of your problem.

Comment: I tried solving it numerically, but I had problems getting a solution that did not break down. However I only tried the simplest method. I will play some more with it numerically tomorrow if I get time.

Comment: Letting $u=1-y$ can reduce the ODE to $u\left(xu''+u'\right)+(u')^4=0$ .

Comment: Considering $x \to 0$ we obtain an asymptotic solution in the form $$y_0(x)=1-\left(1-\frac{2}{3} x \right)^{3/2}$$ which is probably where the series of the OP came from

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $u=1-y$ ,

Then $u'=-y'$

$u''=-y''$

$\therefore\left(-u''-\dfrac{u'}{x}\right)u-\dfrac{(-u')^4}{x}=0$

$u\left(x\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\dfrac{du}{dx}\right)+\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}\right)^4=0$

Let $x=e^t$ ,

Then $t=\ln x$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{du}{dt}=e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}\right)=\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}\right)\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\left(e^{-t}\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}-e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}\right)e^{-t}=e^{-2t}\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}-e^{-2t}\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore u\left(e^{-t}\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}-e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}+e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}\right)+\left(e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}\right)^4=0$

$e^{-t}u\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}+e^{-4t}\left(\dfrac{du}{dt}\right)^4=0$

$u\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}+e^{-3t}\left(\dfrac{du}{dt}\right)^4=0$

Let $u=e^{nt}v$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dt}=e^{nt}\dfrac{dv}{dt}+ne^{nt}v$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}=e^{nt}\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}+ne^{nt}\dfrac{dv}{dt}+ne^{nt}\dfrac{dv}{dt}+n^2e^{nt}v=e^{nt}\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}+2ne^{nt}\dfrac{dv}{dt}+n^2e^{nt}v$

$\therefore e^{nt}v\left(e^{nt}\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}+2ne^{nt}\dfrac{dv}{dt}+n^2e^{nt}v\right)+e^{-3t}\left(e^{nt}\dfrac{dv}{dt}+ne^{nt}v\right)^4=0$

$e^{2nt}v\left(\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}+2n\dfrac{dv}{dt}+n^2v\right)+e^{(4n-3)t}\left(\dfrac{dv}{dt}+nv\right)^4=0$

Choose $2n=4n-3$ , i.e. $n=\dfrac{3}{2}$ , the ODE becomes

$e^{3t}v\left(\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}+3\dfrac{dv}{dt}+\dfrac{9v}{4}\right)+e^{3t}\left(\dfrac{dv}{dt}+\dfrac{3v}{2}\right)^4=0$

$4v\left(4\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}+12\dfrac{dv}{dt}+9v\right)+\left(2\dfrac{dv}{dt}+3v\right)^4=0$

Let $w=\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}=\dfrac{dw}{dt}=\dfrac{dw}{dv}\dfrac{dv}{dt}=w\dfrac{dw}{dv}$

$\therefore4v\left(4w\dfrac{dw}{dv}+12w+9v\right)+\left(2w+3v\right)^4=0$

Let $z=2w+3v$ ,

Then $w=\dfrac{z-3v}{2}$

$\dfrac{dw}{dv}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{dz}{dv}-\dfrac{3}{2}$

$\therefore4v\left(2(z-3v)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{dz}{dv}-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)+6z-9v\right)+z^4=0$

$(z-3v)\dfrac{dz}{dv}-3(z-3v)+6z-9v=-\dfrac{z^4}{4v}$

$(z-3v)\dfrac{dz}{dv}=-3z-\dfrac{z^4}{4v}$

$(12zv+z^4)\dfrac{dv}{dz}=12v^2-4zv$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $p=v+\dfrac{z^3}{12}$ ,

Then $v=p-\dfrac{z^3}{12}$

$\dfrac{dv}{dz}=\dfrac{dp}{dz}-\dfrac{z^2}{4}$

$\therefore12zp\left(\dfrac{dp}{dz}-\dfrac{z^2}{4}\right)=12\left(p-\dfrac{z^3}{12}\right)^2-4z\left(p-\dfrac{z^3}{12}\right)$

$12zp\dfrac{dp}{dz}-3z^3p=12p^2-(2z^3+4z)p+\dfrac{z^6}{12}+\dfrac{z^4}{3}$

$12zp\dfrac{dp}{dz}=12p^2+(z^3-4z)p+\dfrac{z^6}{12}+\dfrac{z^4}{3}$

$p\dfrac{dp}{dz}=\dfrac{p^2}{z}+\dfrac{(z^2-4)p}{12}+\dfrac{z^5}{144}+\dfrac{z^3}{36}$

Let $p=zq$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dp}{dz}=z\dfrac{dq}{dz}+q$

$\therefore zq\left(z\dfrac{dq}{dz}+q\right)=zq^2+\dfrac{(z^2-4)zq}{12}+\dfrac{z^5}{144}+\dfrac{z^3}{36}$

$z^2q\dfrac{dq}{dz}+zq^2=zq^2+\dfrac{(z^2-4)zq}{12}+\dfrac{z^5}{144}+\dfrac{z^3}{36}$

$z^2q\dfrac{dq}{dz}=\dfrac{(z^2-4)zq}{12}+\dfrac{z^5}{144}+\dfrac{z^3}{36}$

$q\dfrac{dq}{dz}=\dfrac{(z^2-4)q}{12z}+\dfrac{z^3}{144}+\dfrac{z}{36}$

Comment: Very nice piece of simplification.  I'll examine what it looks like in the (u,t) domain.  Thank you.